# Micronaut Resilience4j RateLimiter Bean Injection Error

Tags: java, micronaut, resilience4j

I am trying to experiment with Resilience4j and Micronaut. When making a simple cURL request (`curl -X "GET" -L "http://localhost:8080/api/example"`), I receive the following error:

```
09:06:27.228 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Failed to inject value for parameter [rateLimiterEventsConsumerRegistry] of class: io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RateLimiterRegistry

Message: No bean of type [io.github.resilience4j.consumer.EventConsumerRegistry<io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.event.RateLimiterEvent>] exists for the given qualifier: @RateLimiterQualifier. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: new $ExampleController$Definition$Intercepted(BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,List $interceptors) --> new $ExampleController$Definition$Intercepted(BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,[List $interceptors]) --> new RateLimiterInterceptor(ExecutionHandleLocator executionHandleLocator,[RateLimiterRegistry rateLimiterRegistry]) --> RateLimiterRegistry.rateLimiterRegistry(RateLimiterProperties rateLimiterProperties,[EventConsumerRegistry rateLimiterEventsConsumerRegistry],RegistryEventConsumer rateLimiterRegistryEventConsumer,CompositeCustomizer compositeRateLimiterCustomizer)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [rateLimiterEventsConsumerRegistry] of class: io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RateLimiterRegistry

Message: No bean of type [io.github.resilience4j.consumer.EventConsumerRegistry<io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.event.RateLimiterEvent>] exists for the given qualifier: @RateLimiterQualifier. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: new $ExampleController$Definition$Intercepted(BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,List $interceptors) --> new $ExampleController$Definition$Intercepted(BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,[List $interceptors]) --> new RateLimiterInterceptor(ExecutionHandleLocator executionHandleLocator,[RateLimiterRegistry rateLimiterRegistry]) --> RateLimiterRegistry.rateLimiterRegistry(RateLimiterProperties rateLimiterProperties,[EventConsumerRegistry rateLimiterEventsConsumerRegistry],RegistryEventConsumer rateLimiterRegistryEventConsumer,CompositeCustomizer compositeRateLimiterCustomizer)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1079)
    at io.github.resilience4j.micronaut.ratelimiter.$RateLimiterRegistryFactory$RateLimiterRegistry1Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1052)
    at io.github.resilience4j.micronaut.ratelimiter.$RateLimiterInterceptorDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2853)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:3511)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3457)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3427)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBeanRegistrations(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:96)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBeanRegistrations(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2190)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanRegistrationsForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1461)
    at com.example.$ExampleController$Definition$Intercepted$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2853)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1583)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.getTarget(DefaultBeanContext.java:559)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:594)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:246)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.lambda$executeRoute$14(RouteExecutor.java:659)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onSubscribe(ReactorSubscriber.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:601)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:457)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:147)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:224)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:200)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:162)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.github.resilience4j.consumer.EventConsumerRegistry<io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.event.RateLimiterEvent>] exists for the given qualifier: @RateLimiterQualifier. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2805)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1052)
    ... 119 common frames omitted
```

My relevant files are attached below. I see that the examples are using "services." Do I also need to use them, or can I apply the annotations in the Micronaut controller? Thanks!

`ExampleController.java`:

```
package com.example;


import io.github.resilience4j.micronaut.annotation.RateLimiter;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces;

import java.util.UUID;

@Controller("/api/example")
public class ExampleController {
    @Get
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RateLimiter(name = "example")
    public HttpResponse<?> read() {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
                          .toString();

        return HttpResponse.ok(uuid);
    } //read
}
```

`application.yml`:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut_resilience4j
netty:
  default:
    allocator:
      max-order: 3
resilience4j:
  ratelimiter:
    enabled: true
    configs:
      default:
        registerHealthIndicator: false
        limitForPeriod: 10
        limitRefreshPeriod: 1s
        timeoutDuration: 0s
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 100
    instances:
      example:
        baseConfig: default
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut_resilience4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <jdk.version>17</jdk.version>
        <release.version>17</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>3.6.3</micronaut.version>
        <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
        <exec.mainClass>com.example.Application</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-micronaut</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-consumer</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.22</version>
        </dependency>f
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                    <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

                    <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.example</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=micronaut_resilience4j</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem:

`No bean of type [io.github.resilience4j.consumer.EventConsumerRegistry]`

I fixed it by making sure the `consumer` was added to the Gradle.

```
implementation "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-micronaut:${resilience4jVersion}"
implementation "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:${resilience4jVersion}"
implementation "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-consumer:${resilience4jVersion}"
```

That created another problem, there was no bean for `PublisherExtension` so i added the RxJava3 as well:

```
configure("my-project-name") {
apply plugin: "java-library"
ext {
    resilience4jVersion = '2.0.1'
}
dependencies {
    api "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-micronaut:${resilience4jVersion}"
    api "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:${resilience4jVersion}"
    api "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-consumer:${resilience4jVersion}"
    api "io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-rxjava3:${resilience4jVersion}"
}
```

After all of that, I manage to run the `RateLimiter`.

I faced other problems with JVM warmup delaying the first cycle of the Rate period, but for my use case it was not a problem, but [here](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1356) is the issue related to it.